# retrieve index value after sorting Enum alphabetically

Tags: c#, linq

What would be the efficient way of sorting typeof(EnumType) alphabetically?

The enum values have index non-sequential however sorted in alphabetic order.
(i.e.  apple = 5, banana = 2, cantaloupe = 3)

Instantiating temporarily is fine.

Eventually I need the index code for the specific enum value selected.

I am asking because the method I came up with does not look the best:

```
Array tmp = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType));
string[] myenum = tmp.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
Array.Sort(myenum);
int enum_code = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumType), myenum.GetValue((int)selected_index).ToString());
string final_code = enum_code.ToString());
```

Comment: You could simplify lines 2 and 3 by using `OrderBy(o => o.ToString())`. However, I'm not 100% clear what it is you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Because selected index does not directly map the created Array tmp's index value. (Selected index is based on alphabetic order, whereas tmp creates an array with index order, incremental, I need to resort and then retrieve using selected_index variable..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Linq to write more compact and maintainable code.  Unless you're doing this in the inner loop of a high-performance application, I doubt the speed of Linq vs. your original code vs. any other possible implementation will matter at all:

```
var sorted = (from e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Cast<EnumType>()
              orderby e.ToString() select e).ToList();
```

Comment: hi I get following message: Error 837 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Array'.  'OrderBy' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'e'.

Comment: @EricJ. `GetValues` returns `Array`, which implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`, so you'll need a `Cast<EnumType>()` call in there.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error, a more labourious (and .net 2 compatible) solution is;

```
SortedDictionary<string, MyEnumType> list = new SortedDictionary<string, MyEnumType>();
foreach (Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnumType)))
{
    list.Add(e.ToString(), (MyEnumType)e);
}
```

To retrieve the enum;

```
MyEnumType temp = list["SomeValue"];
```

Comment: Sorry, may be my question wasn't clear enough. I eventually need the index for that enum value.